# Retrieve unity container type registration from configuration file in PRISM 7

Tags: wpf, prism, unity-container, prism-7

The configuration section for the unity container:

```
<unity xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/practices/2010/unity">
<container>
  <register type="IProductInfo, Core.Interface" mapTo="Classes.ProductInfo, Core">
    <constructor>
      <param name="Name" value="Product Name" />
      <param name="Version" value="V1.2.65.30865" />
    </constructor>
  </register>
</container>
```

The types are registered in the `App.xaml.cs` file:

```
public partial class App : PrismApplication
{
    protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
    {
      var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
      UnityConfigurationSection section = (UnityConfigurationSection)config.GetSection("unity");
      section?.Configure(containerRegistry.GetContainer());
    }  
}
```

However, because of the container abstraction built in the PRISM 7 version, the container instance doesn't match with the required parameter in the `Configure` method. The following error is produced by the compiler:

> Error CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Unity.IUnityContainer' to 'Microsoft.Practices.Unity.IUnityContainer'

**Question: How can I retrieve the correct container instance to pass as a parameter of the `Configure` method**

P.s. There is already a similar question [on the same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55307647/registertype-from-unity-configuration-file) on StackOverflow. However, the answer doesn't provide a solution to the instantiation problem described above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using incompatible libraries. `UnityConfigurationSection` expects a `Microsoft.Practices.Unity.IUnityContainer` (from an old unity version, three-something, most likely), while `GetContainer` produces a `Unity.IUnityContainer` (from a rather recent unity).

You should either upgrade your `Unity.Configuration` package or downgrade `Prism`...

Comment: Thank you for the provided answer. Just a short notice (maybe you would want to add this to your answer for completeness). Only installing the `Unity.Configuration` section still results in a collision with the `Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration` namespace.  To make it compatible with the newest version of the PRISM framework, the following three NuGet packages should be updated/Installed: `Unity`, `Unity.Abstractions`, `Unity.Configuration`.